# How do I print a Python variable to terminal in json format

Tags: python, json

I am calling a python script from node.js. I want the python script to print json to command-line, so that it may be read by node.js.

I can write a python variable to json file like:

```
import json
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

But I need it to command-line.

tldr:

Write python `names = ["bob", "sally", "ben"]` as json to command-line. I dont want to have to construct the string myself as I want it to work for more complex examples.

Comment: Maybe you mean `print`, not `write`?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json.tool)?

Comment: Well, you can write to `sys.stdout` just like you're writing to a file in the example code.  Or you can use `json.dumps()` instead to produce a string, then print that.

Comment: I would suggest using RPC or a message queue rather than grabbing content off stdout. For example, SocketIO or ZeroMQ

Answer (score 0):

Look into the library package for json (in my case `lib/python3.7/json/tools.py`), and you can find the answer: use `sys.stdout` instead of another file. The full code will be:

```py
import json
import sys

data = []  # your data here
json.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```